# Insert select element using innerHTML (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, select, innerhtml

I'm trying to replace the content in a `td` tag with the id "row2".

Can someone tell me why the `innerHTML` line is not working?

```
var e = document.getElementById("location"); //location is the <select> ID
var area = e.options.selectedIndex;

if (area == 1) {
    var myRow = document.getElementById("row1");
    var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
    document.getElementById("row2").innerHTML = selectList

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
        option.text = array[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.createElement` create an object, not a string. You should add it with `appendChild` instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `appendChild` to insert the new element as a child of the element.

`innerHTML` is the HTML text inside the element, you should not assign an element to it.

Just do this instead:

```
document.getElementById("row2").appendChild(selectList);
```

You can clear it before appending the child by setting `innerHTML` to `""`, but it will count as two updates to the DOM and the browser may repaint or recompute the page two times instead of just one.

A better solution is to replace the child in a single step, using `replaceChild` method:

```
var row2 = document.getElementById("row2");
if (row2.childNodes.length > 0) {
    /* there is already a child attached to the element, so replace it */
    row2.replaceChild(selectList, row2.childNodes.item(0));
} else {
    /* there is no child attached to the element, append it */
    row2.appendChild(selectList);
}
```

These functions are part of the `Node` interface documented by W3C, check it out: [Interface *Node*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1950641247)

Answer (score 0):

`selectList` is not an HTML string. You have to use `appendChild` like you did with the `options`.

**Change**

```
document.getElementById("row2").innerHTML = selectList;
```

**to**

```
document.getElementById("row2").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("row2").appendChild(selectList);
```

innerHTML = "" should avoid duplication.
See a working example at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1zepb25q/1/

Comment: This is what i did first. But i have an if-statement that selects which selectlist of several possible should be added to the HTML. When using .appendChild with this if statement, it will create duplicates if the user changes his/her mind and clicks the same option again. 

In other words im looking to avoid the duplicate(s) .appendChild creates.

Comment: A simple solution would be to empty row2 html before appending the child http://jsfiddle.net/1zepb25q/1/